# Get values from a listview to be sent React-Native

Tags: listview, react-native

I have a problem getting the values of a listview and then sending them.

It is a rating system (RatingBar), I want to get name and rating of each item.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You probably want to add code if you want a better answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <ListView>
    renderRow={(rowData, sec, i) =>
            (
             // you can use button or any other click event here
             <TouchableHighlight
            activeOpacity={75 / 100}
            underlayColor={'rgb(210,210,210)'}
            onPress={() => {
              // You can get value like:
              rowData.name
              // Set them in a state to use anywhere or pass to function from here itself. set state example
              this.setState({
                   name: rowData.name,
              })
            }}
          >

          </TouchableHighlight>
            )

    </ListView>
```